# Change window title rectangle

Tags: windows, winapi

This is possible to change window title rectangle.

For example Windows Explorer some time have such title:

[image: Title1]

Here window title used right area of the window caption, after resizing:

[image]

This title moved to the left part of caption

But I need this:

[image]

On the screenshot you can see red rectangle. This is possible to exclude this area from caption area? After this operation window title should look so:

[image]

Here red rectangle is to visualize only, I don't need any controls on the window caption.

Will be useful something like this:

```
DwmGetWindowAttribute(hWndMain, DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS, @Rt, SizeOf(Rt));
Rt.Left := Rt.Left - 50;
DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWndMain, DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS, @Rt, SizeOf(Rt));
```

But `DwmSetWindowAttribute` does not allow to set `DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my investigating I can tell: Unfortunately no way to do this